# what is the meaning of declaration e.g. void a(string b=0)

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, undefined-behavior, default-arguments

I wrote a function with an optional `string` parameter, but accidentally instead of defaulting it to `""` I defaulted it to `0`:

```
void a(string b=0)
```

I compiled without any warning or else.

Without (!!!) using the content in case of a defaulted parameter (according to other parameters, this one was only used when explicitly set), this caused VERY strange behaviour in nearby code.

Again: I did NOT use that null value'ed string, but got segfaults on changing nearby code locations.

My question, as the compiler did not complain: What is the meaning of that syntax, defaulting some complex parameter (non-numeric, non-pointer) to `0`?

========================================
accidentally wrote

```
void a(string b=0)
```

instead of

```
void a(string b="")
```

expected compiler to failure due to syntax error, but it compiled fine.

Comment: You can construct a `std::string` from a `const char*`. But this must not be `nullptr` (or `0`) - it must be a properly zero-terminated c-string. You've got _undefined behavoir_.

Comment: This is the reason in C++11 `nullptr` was introduced to replace `NULL` (or `0`).

Comment: `0` becomes a null-pointer, essentially `NULL`, and therefore it calls the string constructor that takes a `const char*` - and then it sets fires and creates black holes (undefined behaviour),  but probably not until runtime, so you have time to run for cover. ;)

Comment: Thankfully C++23 deletes the overload taking a `std::nullptr_t`, which should mean this kind of thing gets caught at compile time when overload resolution is performed instead of manifesting as UB.

Comment: Note that this doesn't happen with any number but 0 because no other number has a similar ingrained connection with an address.

Comment: @MarekR I don't think this was the reason. At least it doesnt fix this issue. OP doesnt want to construct a string from a `nullptr` and presence of `nullptr` doesnt prevent `0` to convert to a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When constructing a `std::string` with `0`, the compiler will select the following overloaded constructor for the `std::string` class:

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

However, passing a null pointer as the first argument, instead of a null-terminated c-string, is *undefined behavior*.